# Can not execute method from another class by delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swift 5.1 and do not know if the swift version make it impossible.

I created class in swiftA.swift and SwiftB.swift and I want to execute method in SwiftA.swift.

swiftA.swift:

```
class MySchoolA : CaculateADelegate {
func executeCaculate(_ MyClass,caculateTheNumber index:Int) -> Int {
    return 80
 }
}
```

and in the swiftB.swift

```
protocol CaculateADelegate: AnyObject {
    func executeCaculate(_ MyClass,caculateTheNumber index:Int) -> Int
}

class MyClassB {
    weak var delegate:CaculateADelegate?
    init(){
        let num = delegate?.executeCaculate(self,0)
    }
}
```

the variable num is always nil, where is wrong?

thank you.

Comment: your `delegate` is probably `nil`, make sure you set the delegate before you invoke the method.

Comment: set the delegate of MyClassB to MySchoolA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `init` of class B the delegate is `nil`

```
 weak var delegate:CaculateADelegate?
```

So if you do

```
 let bC = MyClassB() // here it's nil
 bC.delegate = self // here it has a value
```

--

So to work you can do like this by sending the delegate in `init`

```
class MySchoolA : CaculateADelegate {
    func executeCaculate(_ ff:MyClassB,caculateTheNumber index:Int) -> Int {
    return 80
 }
}

protocol CaculateADelegate: AnyObject {
    func executeCaculate(_ ff:MyClassB,caculateTheNumber index:Int) -> Int
}

class MyClassB {
    weak var delegate:CaculateADelegate?
    init(_ del:CaculateADelegate){
        self.delegate = del
        let num = delegate?.executeCaculate(self,caculateTheNumber: 0)
        print(num)
    }
}
```

Test this

```
MyClassB(MySchoolA()) // will print 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not refrencing **delegate to self** in swiftA.swift.

In class swiftA.swift you have instance of swiftB class at that time do 
**swiftB.delegate = self**
and implement protocols in swiftA class

Comment: Yes i agree @Shivam Gaur